# Using PHP Operators with Percentages

Tags: php, operators, percentage

I've been struggling trying to figure this out. I need to compare various sets of values which are %'s (formatted as 5%, 40%, etc) entered by the user. However, using an if statement to see which % is larger doesn't seem to work. For example, the test:

```
<?php 
$var1 = '40%';
$var2 = '5%';
if ($var1 < $var2){
    echo 'var1 is smaller than var2';}
if ($var1 > $var2){
    echo 'var1 is larger than var2';} 
?>
```

equates to say that var1 is smaller than var2. It only seems to be comparing the first digit. For example, if I change the 5% to 3%, it then states that var1 is larger.

The field where they enter this data is used for all sorts of values, so I can't really rely on people entering a number without the % after it. The only way I can seem to figure out to compare them would be to run a str_replace on each variable to remove the % symbol, but I feel like that's pretty inefficient. Is there any better way to compare them??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var1 = "15%";
```

Is a string in PHP, to compare them, you will need to take the intval of the string variable.

```
$var1val = intval($var1);
```

At this point, `$var1val` will equal 15.

You will be able to use this to do your if statement:

```
<?php 

$var1 = intval('40%');
$var2 = intval('5%');

if ($var1 < $var2){
    echo 'var1 is smaller than var2';
}
if ($var1 > $var2){
    echo 'var1 is larger than var2';
}

?>
```

**OR**, in line with the `if`.

```
<?php 

$var1 = '40%';
$var2 = '5%';

if (intval($var1) < intval($var2)){
    echo 'var1 is smaller than var2';
}
if (intval($var1) > intval($var2)){
    echo 'var1 is larger than var2';
} 

?>
```

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of intval. Putting it right in line with the if statement seems to be the cleanest and quickest solution, as I don't have to create new variables or change the existing ones. Works great - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert them to the numbers `40` and `5` rather than strings:

```
$var1 = intval('40%'); // 40
$var2 = intval('5%'); // 5
```

Strings are compared lexicographically, as you've observed, the first character is compared and then the second if the first characters are equal, just like in a dictionary.